# 2 way SSL with Java/Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https

I have an application consuming 2 way SSL enabled webservice and my application is deployed in Tomcat server. I've added truststore/keystore and below variables were set in setenv.sh. This seteenv.sh file was copied to `/usr/local/tomcat/bin/`.

`export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password -Djavax.net.debug=ssl"`

Application is able to establish 2 way SSL connection successfully. Since logs looked clumsy, I tried removing the option `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` from `setenv.sh` file. But once I removed this option, 2 way SSL connection isn't established and SSLHandshakeFailure exception was thrown. On adding `Djavax.net.debug=ssl`, connection is established. I'm unable to understand this behaviour.

Can anyone please explain how removing the debug option disables the SSL connection itself?

Comment: The option javax.net.debug=ssl is only for adding debug logging output to Java's SSL libraries. The error you are seeing is always occurring.

Comment: Nope. Error is occurring only when javax.net.debug=ssl is removed. When I add it to setenv.sh script, handshake is successful and getting 200 response from the service.

Comment: Well that option is not the reason for a successful response.

Comment: Am using OpenJDK. Other than these properties I haven't set anything anywhere.